# Connect monitor to PC without a GPU

Tags: graphics-card, display, cpu, gpu

I am planning to build a gaming computer soon. I have a slight problem... I want to buy a GTX 1080 which is expensive so I will have to wait a few months until I can buy it. I was wondering if I can use my PC without it. My CPU (i7 6700K has a decent integrated graphics processor) but the motherboard (not bought yet, an Asus Rog) has no display connectors / integrated GPU.

Can I connect a VGA monitor in any way and ise the CPU's graphics? Will a convertor cable (VGA to USB) work?

I won't mind if it's slow or has poor quality. I just want to have something that works, because my laptop is broke and I currently have no PC to work on at all.

Comment: most mainstream/Z series motherboards should have some flavour of video out - pretty sure you'd find DP/HDMI. Pretty sure its a non issue and you'd find a connector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several USB-to-Video adapter solutions available. [DisplayLink](http://www.displaylink.com/) offers chipsets that work across several operating systems, and which can be found in a [variety of products](http://www.displaylink.com/products), some quite cheap. The performance, however, is really just adequate for light text-oriented work, and will be dictated by the USB connection speed and the external chipset's speed, not by the quality of your CPU's built-in GPU. Also, some mainboards do not show BIOS information on a USB connected graphics device.

Another option would be just to get a cheap second-hand video card from eBay, that should enable you to "just get some work done" at less than 15 EUR / USD.

But to address your question regarding the integrated graphics capability of the CPU: No, you won't be able to use that without a graphics connector on the mainboard.